# How can I display 2 elements in the same position using css?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div>
<ul class="social-icon">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="social-facebook">
          <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-facebook ff"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want to display this two icon in same position like one icon...Please Help me. Sorry for my Bad English.
[Here is jsfiddle editor link](http://jsfiddle.net/2N2YF/28/)

Comment: To have two elements overlap you have to position them `absolute`:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the following css:

```
.social-facebook {
  position:relative;
}

.fa-facebook {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

Note: You can tweak the left/top properties to your liking.

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2N2YF/32/

Answer (score 1):

```
.fa { position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px;}
```

This should do the trick

Comment: Thanks for your support...but this trick not suitable for my style. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

heres fiddle: [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/tamak/2N2YF/30/)

```
<div>
<ul class="social-icon">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="social-facebook" style="position: relative;">
          <i class="fa fa-facebook" style="list-style: none; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-facebook ff" style="list-style: none; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your support...but this trick not suitable for my style. Thanks again.